# Plone ZMySQLDA, Couldn't install MySQL-python 1.2.4c1 with buildout

Tags: plone, buildout, ploneformgen

I want to use mysql form ploneformgen, but I
Can't buildout plone.

buildout log http://pastie.org/5345272.js

```
Getting required 'MySQL-python>=1.2.1'
  required by Products.ZMySQLDA 3.1.1.
We have no distributions for MySQL-python that satisfies 'MySQL-python>=1.2.1'.
Getting distribution for 'MySQL-python>=1.2.1'.
Running easy_install:
/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/bin/python "-c" "from setuptools.command.easy_install import main; main()" "-mUNxd" "/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/../buildout-cache/eggs/tmpDSODu0" "-Z" "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/downloads/dist/MySQL-python-1.2.4c1.zip"
path=/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.21-py2.6.egg

Processing MySQL-python-1.2.4c1.zip
Running MySQL-python-1.2.4c1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-gFbWLf/MySQL-python-1.2.4c1/egg-dist-tmp-16g1TE
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
install a more recent version first, using
'easy_install -U distribute'.

(Currently using distribute 0.6.19 (/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.6.egg))
error: Setup script exited with 2
An error occured when trying to install MySQL-python 1.2.4c1. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing client1.
  Getting distribution for 'MySQL-python>=1.2.1'.
Error: Couldn't install: MySQL-python 1.2.4c1
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
Products.PloneFormGen = 1.7.1
Products.ZMySQLDA = 3.1.1
collective.classifieds = 1.6
plone.app.ldap = 1.2.8
quintagroup.dropdownmenu = 1.2.5
quintagroup.pfg.captcha = 1.0.5
zettwerk.ui = 1.1.1
```

buildout conf http://pastie.org/5345300

some links:

http://blog.mysqlboy.com/2010/08/installing-mysqldb-python-module.html

http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Plone-amp-MySQL-No-quot-Z-MYSQL-Database-Connection-quot-from-ZMI-td5487160.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the MySQLdb egg requires a newer version of `distribute`:

```
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
```

and

```
(Currently using distribute 0.6.19 (/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.6.egg))
```

Upgrade your `distribute` egg first; if you are using the unified installer, for example, `versions.cfg` pins the version. If so, edit `versions.cfg` to correct the version number there:

```
[versions]
...
# Buildout infrastructure
...
distribute = 0.6.28
```

Comment: @Aitvaras: is there a `distribute =` line in the `versions` section that pins a version number? What `easy_install` script did you use (is it part of the `/user/local/Plone` setup)?

Comment: My buildout.cfg is above. There is no distribute = line in the versions section. 
EasyInstall is a package manager for the Python programming language  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyInstall . I used just for mysql-python

Comment: @Aitvaras: I quite well aware about what `easy_install` is; I was asking where the script is located; it is possible you installed a newer distribute in your system python instead of the python version bundled with Plone. :-)

Comment: @Aitvaras: Also, note the `extends = ` line in the `buildout.cfg` file? That points to a `versions.cfg`; it may well list `distribute` there.

Comment: I found that /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ has 
distribute-0.6.21-py2.6.egg
distribute-0.6.28-py2.6.egg

and 
/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ has only 
distribute-0.6.19-py2.6.egg

Comment: @Aitvaras: Which probably means that the buildout has the `distribute` version pinned; check `versions.cfg` please.

Comment: versions.cfg has distribute = 0.6.21 line . What next I should do?

Comment: @Aitvaras: See my updated answer, edit it and re-run buildout.

Comment: Can I pin distribute to 0.6.28 in versions.cfg ? I tried and it was unsuccessful. When I commented out extends versions in buildout.cfg , buildout was successfull.

Comment: Do not comment out `extends`, that is *not* a good idea! Grep for `distribute` in *all* `.cfg` files, and correct any and all pins you find.

Comment: I commented out 
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/ztk-versions.cfg:#distribute = 0.6.21
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/versions.cfg:#distribute = 0.6.21
also there is in 
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/.installed but I think there is no need to comment it out. 
However buildout still uses distribute 0.6.19 even it picked 0.6.28

Comment: @Aitvaras: Use `bin/buildout annotate` then locate all mentions of `distribute`. Don't comment out, instead correct the version number.

Comment: @Aitvaras: Well, *something* is pinning the `distribute` version to a lower version, and without a crystal ball I cannot see what that might be. You need to check the `bin/buildout annotate` output and see what that tells you.

Comment: It seems that easy_install installs newest distribute on /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages directory.

Comment: @Aitvaras: Exactly, it's part of your system Python, *not* the python install part of the Plone setup.

Comment: @Aitvaras: by updating the pin in versions.cfg, as I told you before. That *should* work, but I have not got enough information from your setup to be able to help you further. I asked you to verify with the `annotate` command that all references to `distribute` have been pinned correctly.

Comment: @Aitvaras: Right, at which point `bin/buildout -v` should update the `distribute` version. That is still the case?

Comment: that output is the same. However, I cd /usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/bin and ./easy_install -U distribute . That upgraded the right distribute. after that I ran ./bin/buildout and everything works now

Comment: I am very thankful for your help. I was hitting the wall several days (just a newbie for Plone). I would buy you a beer.

Comment: Also, everybody should note that you need 
apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev libmysqlclient15-dev
 on your system. explanation is in my some provided links

Answer (score 1):

While you have a perfectly good answer for the specific problem, I highly recommend forgetting about ZMySQLDA and use SQLAlchemyDA which gives you access to any database supported by SQLAlchemy (I've used all of MySQL, PostGreSQL, Oracle, SQLServer) with a single product, and is better supported.

Comment: I am the very beginner of using Plone, Zope and python, so still find it very usefull. However, I will take your suggestion into account and  move to SQLALchemyDA. A good tutorial is all what I need know :)